# System.Diagnostics.Process.Start C# authentication issue

Tags: c#, process

System.Diagnostics.Process.Start C# authentication issues:

I am tying to write a coded UI test which can call external function (I know how to call a batch file but here I would like to call the exe using C# code)

Here is my code, I can bring up the log in window sometime. But it does not seem to authenticate.

```
public void Login()
{
    Char[] input = "********".ToCharArray();
    SecureString SecurePassword = new SecureString();

    for (int idx = 0; idx < input.Length; idx++)
    {
        SecurePassword.AppendChar(input[idx]);
    }
    SecureString secure = SecurePassword;
    string FileName = @"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Helium\\Edition\\7.0\\Gateway\\UserShell.exe";
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(FileName, "pAlan",secure,"");
}
```

Test method `CodedUITest2.CodedUITestMethod1` threw exception:

> ```
> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The stub received bad data
> ```

Answer (score 4):

Try declaring a ProcessStartInfo variable, and don't use empty Domain Parameter. If you are not under domain, use the local machine name.

Try using also de runas verb to impersonate with that user:

```
ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
processStartInfo.UserName = "pAlan";
processStartInfo.Password = secure;
processStartInfo.Verb = "runas";
processStartInfo.Domain = MachineName;
Process.Start(processStartInfo);
```